# Can I learn what [learning] is?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta, burninate-request

The tag [learning](/questions/tagged/learning) on this site seems to have no clear purpose, with questions ranging from "learning how to use the site" to "learning about topics". It seems to meet the definition of a too-broad tag.

Should it be removed? Or is there a clear purpose we can define it to?

Comment: Also feels like a very classic meta tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to the positive community consensus, for the past few days, I've been gradually removing this tag. Today, there were four uses, and I just removed it from all of them.

Thus, this is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Answer (score 6):

On review, this does feel like a classic meta tag, and it seems like something of very limited value. It should be fine to burninate. It's a slightly more used tag so do remember to be mindful of the front page when editing.